# Unable to close flash message in Django

Tags: python, django

I am developing a sample application using python and Django framework . In this i have shown flash message with cancel [**x**] icon to close the message using **Django Messages Framework** in **index.html** using **base.html** as **(template inheritance)**.

**PROBLEM :** The problem is although i am able to display the message in index.html , but i cannot **cancel** it. Below are the code files

**base.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %} Harry Ice Creams</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Harry Ice Creams</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Services
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/services">Ice Cream</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Waffle</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Shake</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

// -----------------------FLASH MESSAGE CODE BELOW-----------------------------

{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show my-0" role="alert">
  {{ message }}
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% block body %}{% endblock body %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid my-4 px-0">
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      {% comment %} <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x600/?icecream" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> {% endcomment %}
        <img src="/static/img/1.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Chocolate Cookie Dough</h5>
        <p>This is warm treat cookies ice cream - vanilla. It's the perfect mixture of two desserts that customers already love. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      {% comment %} <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x600/?icecreams" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> {% endcomment %}
      <img src="/static/img/2.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Moose Tracks</h5>
        <p>This fun treat has a lot of chunks! It's vanilla ice cream, peanut butter cups, and fudge. It's a new perspective for vanilla ice cream.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      {% comment %} <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x600/?cakes" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> {% endcomment %}
      <img src="/static/img/3.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Chocolate Frosted Doughnut</h5>
        <p>Covered with chocolate layer and sprinkles, this doughnut is definitely for chocolate lovers.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container my-3">
<h1 class="my-4 text-center">Select from our range of Ice Creams</h1>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/4.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/5.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/6.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/7.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/8.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/9.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/10.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
           <img src="/static/img/11.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="/static/img/12.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="900" height="400">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from home.models import Contact
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    context = {
        'variable': 'This is a TEST variable',
        'name': 'MOHIT'
    }
    messages.success(request,'This is a test message')
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')


def services(request):
    return render(request, 'services.html')


def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        desc = request.POST.get('desc')
        contact = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone=phone,
                          desc=desc, date=datetime.today())
        contact.save()

        # -------------------SENDING FLASH MESSAGE------------------------        

        messages.success(request, 'Your message has been sent successfully.')
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

**any solution please ?**

Answer (score 0):

Call the jQuery library in your code.